# Installing Elasticsearch on Minikube using Helm3

Tags: minikube, elk

I want to deploy the elastic stack on minikube using Helm3. I downloaded add the repo to my helm chart repository and then installed it using helm install. The pods get deployed but when I check their status using kubectl describe pod, it shows that the readiness probe has failed.

I tried the solutions mentioned in #783 but it did not work. I dont know what is going wrong. I just have to install the already available repository from the official helm website and install it but it is not working for me

Below are the logs of the elasticsearch container that keepds failing and causes the pod to restart:

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:55.416Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"elected-as-master ([2] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {elasticsearch-master-0}{60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ}{3p3vKg7nSLavgSf4iZAXxQ}{elasticsearch-master-0}{10.244.0.30}{10.244.0.30:9300}{cdhilmrstw} completing election, {elasticsearch-master-1}{dSUotEIsS3az8cFUpwNxKg}{WjnyF3s9QGW6ZOX0kPnMGg}{elasticsearch-master-1}{10.244.0.29}{10.244.0.29:9300}{cdhilmrstw} completing election], term: 243, version: 2392, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{elasticsearch-master-0}{60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ}{3p3vKg7nSLavgSf4iZAXxQ}{elasticsearch-master-0}{10.244.0.30}{10.244.0.30:9300}{cdhilmrstw}]}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][masterService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:55.550Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"failing [elected-as-master ([2] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {elasticsearch-master-0}{60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ}{3p3vKg7nSLavgSf4iZAXxQ}{elasticsearch-master-0}{10.244.0.30}{10.244.0.30:9300}{cdhilmrstw} completing election, {elasticsearch-master-1}{dSUotEIsS3az8cFUpwNxKg}{WjnyF3s9QGW6ZOX0kPnMGg}{elasticsearch-master-1}{10.244.0.29}{10.244.0.29:9300}{cdhilmrstw} completing election]]: failed to commit cluster state version [2392]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][masterService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.FailedToCommitClusterStateException","error.message":"node is no longer master for term 243 while handling publication","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.FailedToCommitClusterStateException: node is no longer master for term 243 while handling publication\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.Coordinator.publish(Coordinator.java:1426)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.publish(MasterService.java:476)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.publishClusterStateUpdate(MasterService.java:367)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.runTasks(MasterService.java:304)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.run(MasterService.java:170)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:110)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:148)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:825)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:257)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:223)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:56.113Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"master node changed {previous [], current [{elasticsearch-master-1}{dSUotEIsS3az8cFUpwNxKg}{WjnyF3s9QGW6ZOX0kPnMGg}{elasticsearch-master-1}{10.244.0.29}{10.244.0.29:9300}{cdhilmrstw}]}, term: 245, version: 2392, reason: ApplyCommitRequest{term=245, version=2392, sourceNode={elasticsearch-master-1}{dSUotEIsS3az8cFUpwNxKg}{WjnyF3s9QGW6ZOX0kPnMGg}{elasticsearch-master-1}{10.244.0.29}{10.244.0.29:9300}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.allocated_processors_double=1.0, ml.machine_memory=512000000, ml.max_jvm_size=134217728, xpack.installed=true, ml.allocated_processors=1}}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][clusterApplierService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:58.425Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"removed {{elasticsearch-master-2}{4Ptjq7NFSbu1hEfM_qDx6A}{jfkIoB8bSEmNNLd8c71xVw}{elasticsearch-master-2}{10.244.0.31}{10.244.0.31:9300}{cdhilmrstw}}, term: 245, version: 2393, reason: ApplyCommitRequest{term=245, version=2393, sourceNode={elasticsearch-master-1}{dSUotEIsS3az8cFUpwNxKg}{WjnyF3s9QGW6ZOX0kPnMGg}{elasticsearch-master-1}{10.244.0.29}{10.244.0.29:9300}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.allocated_processors_double=1.0, ml.machine_memory=512000000, ml.max_jvm_size=134217728, xpack.installed=true, ml.allocated_processors=1}}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][clusterApplierService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:58.533Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][generic][T#2]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","tags":[" [.kibana-event-log-8.5.1-000001][0]"]}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:58.595Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][generic][T#2]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","tags":[" [.geoip_databases][0]"]}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:58.622Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][generic][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","tags":[" [.apm-custom-link][0]"]}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:58.720Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][generic][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","tags":[" [.apm-agent-configuration][0]"]}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:58.735Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][generic][T#3]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","tags":[" [.kibana_security_session_1][0]"]}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:04:59.282Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"[[.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2023.09.20-000001][0]] failed to perform indices:admin/seq_no/retention_lease_sync on replica [.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2023.09.20-000001][0], node[4Ptjq7NFSbu1hEfM_qDx6A], [R], s[STARTED], a[id=q87Tqct5SDqS0sppjyg9PA]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][scheduler][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.index.seqno.RetentionLeaseSyncAction","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.client.internal.transport.NoNodeAvailableException","error.message":"unknown node [4Ptjq7NFSbu1hEfM_qDx6A]","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.client.internal.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: unknown node [4Ptjq7NFSbu1hEfM_qDx6A]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReplicasProxy.performOn(TransportReplicationAction.java:1264)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.ReplicationOperation$3.tryAction(ReplicationOperation.java:280)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.RetryableAction$1.doRun(RetryableAction.java:100)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:892)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$1.run(ThreadPool.java:436)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)\n\tSuppressed: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [elasticsearch-master-2][10.244.0.31:9300] Node not connected\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.ClusterConnectionManager.getConnection(ClusterConnectionManager.java:280)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.getConnection(TransportService.java:811)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:715)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReplicasProxy.performOn(TransportReplicationAction.java:1278)\n\t\t... 11 more\n\tSuppressed: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [elasticsearch-master-2][10.244.0.31:9300] Node not connected\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.ClusterConnectionManager.getConnection(ClusterConnectionManager.java:280)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.getConnection(TransportService.java:811)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:715)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReplicasProxy.performOn(TransportReplicationAction.java:1278)\n\t\t... 11 more\n\tSuppressed: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [elasticsearch-master-2][10.244.0.31:9300] Node not connected\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.ClusterConnectionManager.getConnection(ClusterConnectionManager.java:280)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.getConnection(TransportService.java:811)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:715)\n\t\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReplicasProxy.performOn(TransportReplicationAction.java:1278)\n\t\t... 11 more\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:05:02.334Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"839 finished with response BulkByScrollResponse[took=9.2s,timed_out=false,sliceId=null,updated=138,created=0,deleted=0,batches=1,versionConflicts=0,noops=0,retries=0,throttledUntil=0s,bulk_failures=[],search_failures=[]]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][transport_worker][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.tasks.LoggingTaskListener","trace.id":"bfcb92a520b8c3bd2c0dfe9a4826f612","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-20T06:05:10.102Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"[gc][174] overhead, spent [497ms] collecting in the last [1s]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][scheduler][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm.JvmGcMonitorService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"qp1jTxH0S5urH-CaQ6Evfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"60pIbgQHS8C70-GxBBhInQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}

ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I managed to do the same thing following this [tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/elasticsearch-helm-chart). Hope it helps.